# Universal aggregate initialization by variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates

This is an interesting problem I'm thinking about a time ago.
Given a `struct` with an underlying aggregate:

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct A
{
   constexpr A() = default;

   template <typename ... Ts>
   constexpr A(const T& value, const Ts& ... values); // magic

   std::array<T, N> arr; // aggregate
};
```

**How would you implement variadic template constructor `A(const T& value, const Ts& ... values)` to**

- accept both values of type `T` and another `A<T, N>`
- properly initialize the underlying aggregate based on the values represented by the passed arguments
- respect the capacity of the aggregate
- support C++14 constexpr rules and do not introduce any runtime overhead

---

Satisfying the above requirements, it is possible to do the following:

```
int main()
{
   A<int, 3> x(1, 2, 3);
   A<int, 2> y(1, 2);

   A<int, 6> a(x, 1, 2, 3);
   A<int, 6> b(1, x, 2, 3);
   A<int, 6> c(1, 2, x, 3);
   A<int, 6> d(1, 2, 3, x);
   A<int, 6> e(x, x);
   A<int, 6> f(y, y, y);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the expected value of `y[2]` in `A<int,3> y(1,2);`?

Comment: What about runtime overhead of constructor invocation?

Comment: @VaughnCato thanks for the catch, that was a mistype, updated now

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg a constexpr implies inline, so we can't speak about invocation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one approach that works, but could almost certainly be improved on.

We have a constructor for `A` that takes a parameter pack, converts each element into a tuple, concatenates the tuples together to make for one large tuple, and then simply uses aggregate initialization from that big tuple. All of the following can be `constexpr`, I just omitted it for brevity.

First we do the conversion:

```
template <class... Us>
A(Us const&... us)
: A(std::tuple_cat(as_tuple(us)...))
{ }
```

With:

```
// single argument
template <class U>
auto as_tuple(U const& u) {
    return std::forward_as_tuple(u);
}

// aggregate argument
template <size_t M>
auto as_tuple(A<T, M> const& a) {
    return as_tuple(a, std::make_index_sequence<M>{});
}

template <size_t M, size_t... Is>
auto as_tuple(A<T, M> const& a, std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
    return std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<Is>(a.arr)...);
}
```

And then we just initialize from there:

```
template <class... Us, class = std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Us) <= N)>>
A(std::tuple<Us...> const& t)
: A(t, std::index_sequence_for<Us...>{})
{ }

template <class... Us, size_t... Is>
A(std::tuple<Us...> const& t, std::index_sequence<Is...> )
: arr{{std::get<Is>(t)...}}
{ }
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbbbb11598b82671)

Comment: The only thing I'd add is to use `forward_as_tuple` instead, to reduce copying.

Answer (score 6):

The answer by @Barry is certainly correct and acceptable. But it requires some C++14 library additions (which you could probably also write yourself in C++11), and overall requires some good `tuple`- and meta-programming fu.

Let's view multiple arguments a "range of ranges", where a range is just a pointer and a size. Scalar arguments are just a size-1 range, and `A<T, N>` arguments are size-N ranges.

```
template<class T>
struct Range
{
    T const* data_;
    std::size_t size_;

    constexpr T const* begin() const noexcept { return data_; }
    constexpr T const* end() const noexcept { return data_ + size_; }
    constexpr std::size_t size() const noexcept { return size_; }
};

template<class T>
constexpr Range<T> as_range(T const& t)
{
    return { &t, 1 };
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct A;

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr Range<T> as_range(A<T, N> const& a)
{
    return { a.arr, N };    
}
```

You can then simply do a double loop over all elements of all ranges

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct A
{
    T arr[N]; // aggregate

    constexpr A() = default;

    template <typename U, typename... Us>
    constexpr A(U const u, Us const&... us)
    : 
        arr{}
    {
        Range<T> rngs[1 + sizeof...(Us)] { as_range(u), as_range(us)... };
        auto i = 0;
        for (auto const& r : rngs)
            for (auto const& elem : r)
                arr[i++] = elem;
        assert(i == N);                
    }
};
```

[**Live Example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QbK8jXcy9O38ROfZ) working at compile-time (requires GCC >= 6.0 or Clang >= 3.4)

```
template <class T, size_t N>
void print(A<T, N> const& a) {
    for (T const& t : a.arr) {
        std::cout << t << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    constexpr A<int, 3> x(1, 2, 3);
    constexpr A<int, 2> y(1, 2);

    constexpr A<int, 6> a(x, 1, 2, 3);
    constexpr A<int, 6> b(1, x, 2, 3);
    constexpr A<int, 6> c(1, 2, x, 3);
    constexpr A<int, 6> d(1, 2, 3, x);
    constexpr A<int, 6> e(x, x);
    constexpr A<int, 6> f(y, y, y);

    print(a); // 1 2 3 1 2 3
    print(b); // 1 1 2 3 2 3
    print(c); // 1 2 1 2 3 3 
    print(d); // 1 2 3 1 2 3
    print(e); // 1 2 3 1 2 3
    print(f); // 1 2 1 2 1 2    
}
```

Comment: Although the approach itself is valid and somewhat easier to follow (due to the absence of template meta-programming), the _"do not introduce any runtime overhead"_ specification is missed.

Comment: @black thanks, FTFY. Note that this requires changing the data member from `std::array<T,N>` to a `T[N]` C-array because the non-const  `operator[]` for the former is not `constexpr`.